# Jenkins pipeline upload file to Slack

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, slack, slack-api

I have a Jenkins pipeline that sends an alert to Slack. Now I want to add the ability to upload files to Slack. But the file is not sent.

This is sending messages to slack. And it works.

```
slackSend(
    color: color_slack_msg(),
    message: """
        Some message
    """.stripIndent().trim(),
    channel: "${env.SLACK_ID}, ${env.SLACK_NOTIFICATION_ID}",
    tokenCredentialId: 'slack_notification'
)
```

This is a file upload to Slack.

```
slackUploadFile (
    channel: '${env.SLACK_METRICS_ID}', 
    credentialId: 'slack_notification', 
    filePath: 'metrics_editor.txt', 
    initialComment: 'Test comment'
)
```

After executing the slackUploadFile script, I see the message in the Jenkins logs:

```
Using dirname=some\path\to\project and includeMask=metrics_editor.txt
Adding file some\path\to\project\metrics_editor.txt
```

But the file is not uploaded to Slack.

I see that Credential is configured correctly since slackSend is working.

I tried this:

```
curl -sSL -D - -X POST -F file=@<path_to_file> -F token=<bot_token> https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

In response I receive:

```
file=@metrics_editor.txt -F channels=<channel id> -F token=<token>https://slack.com/api/files.upload
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Thu, 21 Sep 2023 14:37:51 GMT
server: Apache
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-slack-req-id: <id>
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 0
x-robots-tag: noindex,nofollow
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
access-control-expose-headers: x-slack-req-id, retry-after
access-control-allow-headers: slack-route, x-slack-version-ts, x-b3-traceid, x-b3-spanid, x-b3-parentspanid, x-b3-sampled, x-b3-flags
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-slack-unique-id: <id>
x-slack-backend: r
referrer-policy: no-referrer
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 35
via: 1.1 slack-prod.tinyspeck.com, envoy-www-iad-maoxshte, envoy-edge-fra-uzwtdosi
x-envoy-attempt-count: 1
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 101
x-backend: files_normal files_canary_with_overflow files_control_with_overflow
x-server: slack-www-hhvm-files-iad-xskh
x-slack-shared-secret-outcome: no-match
x-edge-backend: envoy-www
x-slack-edge-shared-secret-outcome: no-match

{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_auth"}
```

I also found that in the settings of the Jenkins application in Slack you need to give permissions to upload files `files:write`, but I don't know where to find this permission.
I found Jenkins in Installed Applications, but the permissions page is empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKZ3i.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be bug in plugin, as i see slack endpoints were changed recently

it doesnt work with simple token(jenkins ci webhook) by some reason but **works** with slack application bot token

i tested this:

```
node {
    sh "echo hey > blah.txt"
    slackUploadFile filePath: "*.txt", channel: "#testing-slack-api", initialComment:  "HEY HEY", credentialId: "slack-bot-token"
}
```

where slack-bot-token is token from slack app "Bot User OAuth Token".

you can pass token from code, or configure it globally in jenkins global settings -> slack
and slack app configured via https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack/#plugin-content-creating-your-app

also added app to slack channel as @myappname -> yes, invite app to channel

you can find your slack apps via

1. go to any channel you have and click on name
2. go to integration tab
3. press add apps
4. press manage apps (top left corner)
5. click Build on top right corner
6. press Create New App
7. everything else you can find in documentation

Comment: Note that it is `credentialId`, not `credentialsId`